# ApplicationListener not working with Junit

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have some test classes and i want to perform a functionality at the end end of all the test classes, hence I am trying to use ApplicationListener for events like ContextClosedEvent or ContextStoppedEvent but nothing seems to work and the implemented method is not called at all during the execution of the test cases.

Please suggest on what could be the possible cause of this behavior.

Comment: are you looking something different from teardown functionality from junit?

Comment: @techtrainer - Yes I was looking for something different. For now, I have removed it at all so I do not need such behavior anymore.